# IE10: Pseudo-Elements - can't play Animations more than once

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, animation

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}

div.skew:before {
    -webkit-animation: skew 1s linear;
    -moz-animation:    skew 1s linear;
    animation:         skew 1s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes skew {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: skew(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: skew(50deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes skew {
    0%   { -moz-transform: skew(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: skew(50deg); }
}

@keyframes skew {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: skew(0deg);  transform: skew(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: skew(50deg); transform: skew(50deg); }
}
```

**jQuery** (adds `.skew` class to `div` to trigger the animation upon hover)

```
$("div").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("skew");  
});

$("div").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("skew");
});
```

**SEE HERE** (Internet Explorer 10)
http://jsfiddle.net/uDddG/

Works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE10 the animation can trigger only once when it's on a :before or :after pseudo-element. I thought it might've been a problem with `animationend`, but it works fine on non-pseudo-elements. What's wrong here?

**---EDIT---**

I think the problem might be something related to the jQuery above, instead of using jQuery to add .skew class upon hovering the div, I tried `div:hover:before` instead of `div.skew:before` and the animation can trigger any time upon hover.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/yaBWa/.

But I need the animation to finish in case the the div becomes unhovered while it's still playing, so using `:hover` instead of `.mouseenter` to add .skew class to trigger the animation isn't an option.